# What hotels will prepare dinner as specified by the customer?

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels

Since I eat a lot, I easily get into trouble when travelling. I cannot survive for long eating the typical restuarant menus, I need to be able to order the right quantities of ingredients such as the amount of carbs, fats etc. When this is not possible I have to improvise (eating dinner twice etc.) but it's then difficult to eat enough. I end up feeling hungry all day and my focus will shift to where I can get the next meal instead of what I am supposed to be doing. In emergency cases, I can deal with this for a few days, but then I have to get back home.

When I have to stay for longer, I simply book an expensive hotel but then the costs are not paid by me. I was wondering if there are cheaper hotels (price range below, say, $130 per day) where they by default can prepare dinner when requested by the customer.

Comment: Is staying in a hotel with a kitchen in the room an option? For instance, Marriott has its Residence Inn brand, Hilton has Homewood Suites, and so on.

Comment: The problem with that or staying in an appartment is that I would arrive and immediately have to know my way in the local supermarkets. Also I need the right equipment, like weighing scales that either has to be present there or I have to bring that with me.

Comment: @CountIblis Most of the extended stay chains (Residence, Homewood, et al) offer grocery shopping services. If you leave a list with housekeeping in the morning, the fridge/cupboard will be stocked by dinnertime.

Comment: What about packing/buying some snacks to eat before or after dinner?

Comment: LessPop_MoreFizz, I'll take a look at Residence and Homewood.

Comment: Bernhard, that's what I do when I can't arrange for my dinner to be prepared according to specification. I can do this for a few days, but it's not going to work long term. The problem is that I need to eat so much (about 4000 kcal/day) that my hunger feeling isn't a good guide to tell me if I had enough to eat at some meal. If I eat a lot less one day, I don't notice that until a day later. Last year I was close to the limit, after a week I was feeling extremely hungry all day, after eating my stomach completely full that hungry feeling only increased.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - do you want to order dinner at non-dinner times, or control precisely what food is in your dinner?

Comment: Control the quantities of the food in the dinner. What doesn't work is if they serve some amount of potatoes and they tell me to just order more if I need more. What I would need is about 1 kg of potatoes.

Comment: @CountIblis Just out of curiosity, don't feel obliged to answer, and please don't feel offended, but do you have some kind of disease that causes this? Or are you some pro-athlete training for <...>?

Comment: Bernhard, it did feel like a disease when I was about 20 and this problem started to get worse. I started to faint from hunger despite eating normal quantities of food (glucose levels were abnormally low given what I had eaten). A large number of test had been done and they came all out negative for any disease. Eventually I did learn to live with this problem, I'm probably physiologically normal, it's just that my metabolic rate is double of someone of my weight.

Comment: I do actually exercise a lot, but even without exercise I would need to eat a lot. Exercise helps me with my energy levels. I run 5 times a week for 50 minutes.

Comment: Don't know where you are looking for this, but around here buffet restaurants are quite common. You just serve yourself at a buffet whatever you want in whatever quantity. Sometimes it's a fixed price "all you can eat", but here in Switzerland charging by weight is quite common as well.